# LaTeX3 - Failing to define the default value of a package option

Tags: latex3, package-options

I fail to obtain a default value for an option of a package. What is a good way to obtain a default "string" value for an option?

Here is what I have tried.

```
% File: main.sty

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage{main}{}{}{}

\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}


\keys_define:nn {main_opts} {
    lang .tl_set:N  = \l_main_opt_lang,
    lang .default:n = \tl_set:Nn\l_main_opt_lang{EN},
}

\ProcessKeysPackageOptions{main_opts}


\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{}{
    LANG = \l_main_opt_lang
}
```

---

```
% LaTeX file to test

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[lang=FR]{main}   % OK
%\usepackage{main}            % KO

\begin{document}

\test{}

\end{document}
```

PS: is there a good tutorial about boolean and key-value like options for packages and also macros using the `LaTeX3` machinery?

Comment: You don’t need `\RequirePackage{expl3}`. This is loaded down by default. I guess this was always the case when you did `\ProvidesExplPackage`, but even standard LaTeX2e now (as of last Summer, I think) loads down `expl3` and most of `xparse` by default.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have just copied and pasted a code, to be honest. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are not looking for a *default* value, you are looking to set the *initial* value (at least in `l3keys` parlance).

The *default* value becomes relevant if a key is given without a value. The *initial* value becomes relevant if a key is not used at all.

```
\begin{filecontents}{main.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage{main}{}{}{}

\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}


\keys_define:nn {main_opts}
  {
    lang .tl_set:N  = \l_main_opt_lang,
    lang .initial:n = EN,
  }

\ProcessKeysPackageOptions{main_opts}


\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{}
  {
    LANG = \l_main_opt_lang
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\usepackage[lang=FR]{main}   % OK
\usepackage{main}            % KO

\begin{document}

\test{}

\end{document}
```

gives

> LANG=EN

---

Some more details from the [documentation `interface3`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf), Chapter 26 *The `l3keys` package Key–value interfaces*

> `⟨key⟩ .default:n = {⟨default⟩}`
>
> Creates a ⟨default⟩ value for ⟨key⟩, which is used if no value is given.
> This will be used if only the key name is given, but not if a blank ⟨value⟩ is given:
>
> ```
> \keys_define:nn { mymodule }
> {
>   key .code:n = Hello~#1,
>   key .default:n = World
> }
> \keys_set:nn { mymodule }
> {
>   key = Fred, % Prints ’Hello Fred’
>   key,        % Prints ’Hello World’
>   key = ,     % Prints ’Hello ’
> }
> ```
>
> The default does not affect keys where values are required or forbidden. Thus a required value cannot be supplied by a default value, and giving a default value for a key which cannot take a value does not trigger an error.

and

> `⟨key⟩ .initial:n = {⟨value⟩}`
>
> Initialises the ⟨key⟩ with the ⟨value⟩, equivalent to
>
> ```
> \keys_set:nn {⟨module⟩} { ⟨key⟩ = ⟨value⟩ }
> ```

In this example a *default* value probably does not make a lot of sense and I would probably want to explicitly make passing an empty argument an error by setting `.value_required:n = true`

```
\keys_define:nn {main_opts}
  {
    lang .tl_set:N  = \l_main_opt_lang,
    lang .initial:n = EN,
    lang .value_required:n = true,
  }
```